# showCategory + showValue calculate BMI

Tags: java

This is my calculator for BMI, but the error "symbol 'showValue()' can't found", do I need to add any variables in the main method, or in the parentheses of the showCategory(showValue())?

```
{
double bmi = bmi1.showValue();
System.out.println("Your BMI index:" + bmi + "。");

String x = bmi1.showCategory(showValue()); //error comes out from here
System.out.println("Your BMI level:" + x);
}
```

My first class "Calculator"

```
class Calculator
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
{ 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

System.out.println("You're Height(cm)"); 
String str1 = br.readLine(); 

System.out.println("You're Weight(kg)"); 
String str2 = br.readLine(); 

double height = Double.parseDouble(str1); 
double weight = Double.parseDouble(str2); 

BMI bmi1 = new BMI(); 

bmi1.setHeight(height); 
bmi1.setWeight(weight); 

double h = bmi1.getHeight(); 
double w = bmi1.getWeight(); 

System.out.println("Your height is:" + h + "cm。" + "Your weight is:" + w + "kg。"); 

double bmi = bmi1.showValue(); 
System.out.println("Your BMI index is:" + bmi + "。"); 

String x = bmi1.showCategory(showValue()); 
System.out.println("Your BMI level is:" + x); 
} 
}
```

My second class "BMI",

```
public class BMI 
{
double height;
double weight;

double getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

double getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}

void setHeight(double h)
{
    height = h;
}

void setWeight(double w)
{
    weight = w;
}

double showValue()
{
    double bmi = weight / ((height / 100) * (height / 100));
    return bmi;
}
```

double showCategory is the BMI level list for the variables,

Have change many values in between the parentheses, but the error is still there,
would like to know how should I put so that it can run,

Comment: try `String x = bmi1.showCategory(bmi1.showValue());`